# converting higher order transfer function in s-domanin to the cascaded biquad transfer functions, also in s-domain

Tags: matlab, continuous-signals

I'm trying to convert a transfer function (tf) in s-domain (`num: b17*s**18 + b16*s**17 + ... + b0, den= s**20 + a18*s**19 + ... a0`) to cascade of the biquad transfer functions, also in s-domain. That is my flow:

1. Convert s-domain tf with numerator (num) and denominator (den) to the 
   z-domain tf mit numd and dend:

   ```
   [numd dend] = bilinear(num, den, f);  // f= resonance frequency of plant
   ```
2. Convert z-domain tf to the cascaded biquad filters:

   ```
   [sos] = tf2sos (numd, dend);`
   ```
3. Finally Convert biquad filters from z-domain to s-domain, e.g. for the first
   biquad: However before running d2c I generate H:

   ```
   H = tf([0.2046 0.4251 0.2014], [1.0000 2.6487 1.7591], 1/fs) 
                                         // fs = sample frequency
   ```

   I get the following error:
       `'Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.'`

What is wrong? Is there any other way which is superior to my flow?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to convert to and from the $z$-domain? Just compute the poles and zeros of the transfer function, and split them up in complex conjugate pairs. If there are real-valued roots, take two of them together in one biquad.

Comment: I have to simulate the whole system (closed loop) in mixed-mode, i.e. controller in HDL (digital) and the proposed transfer function in analog model. implementing a transfer function with very high order is not practically efficient. By splitting it in different sub-tf 2en order one can have a flexible model.

Comment: I understand why you want to split the transfer function into second order blocks, but the question remains why you go from $s$ to $z$ and back to $s$; that's not necessary, because you have an analog model for the transfer function, so you could do as I suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: jojek, thanks for your reply. Actually I generated poles/zeros (18 zeros and 20 poles akk complex). How can I distribute it in 10 transfer functions of 2en order with the real zeros/poles?